# Vue Component is Receiving only the First Parameter Defined in Props

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9

I am facing a strange issue and can't figure out why. I am using `Vuejs 3` inside the `Laravel` application. I have created a component that receives **two (2)** parameters (both are numeric values) through `props`. However while debugging, only the first parameter is passed while the second (or remaining) parameters are `undefined`

My Vue Component: "**MyComponent**"

```
<template>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {

    props: ['w_no', 'key'],
    
    mounted() {

        alert(this.w_no);
        alert(this.key);

    },


}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

In my Blade file

```
<my-component w_no="{{ $w_no }}" key="{{ $key }}" />
```

I have checked these values in my blade and it is receiving the correct values from the controller. But Vue is not receiving the second parameter. It says "**Undefined**"

[image]

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: I think the question needs more information. How exactly do you get `$w_no` and `$key` in your blade file?

Comment: @cSharp I am getting these values from the controller passed to view and I am getting the correct data in blade (I have checked)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are encountering this problem because `key` is a [special attribute](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key) in Vue 3.